# WhatsApp custom url scheme not working in a Webview

Tags: android, url, android-webview, whatsapp

I am doing webview in android in which I am calling a website link in that website I am calling **web.whatsapp.com** link. Now this link is working good in desktop as well as mobile view while the same link if I open in webview then showing error i.e. **web page is not available** for more clear let see the error image

[image]

Here is the code of webview android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        bar =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://.../");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient{

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setVisibility(webView.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can see it redirects you to `whatsapp://...` URL, and `whatsapp://` protocol is not supported by the WebView obviously, as it is a custom whatsapp protocol. If you open such link in the browser, it will start the Whatsapp application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to `override shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in your web client and use code given below .

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    boolean overrideUrlLoading = false;

    if (url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {

        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

        overrideUrlLoading = true;

    } else {

        view.loadUrl(url);
    }

    return overrideUrlLoading;
}
```